# I have to log in with my old email here on ask ubuntu even though I already changed the email

Tags: discussion, login

I have to log in with my old email here on askubuntu even though I already changed the email.

What do I do to log in on ask ubuntu with my new email?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why is it still possible to log in to Ask Ubuntu with my old email address after I added a new one?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18363/8698)